# Android Studio/Flutter - field names missing on debug watch breakpoint

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging

App stopped on breakpoint:
[image]

As you can see, there's only field values. Field names are missing.

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.5
Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Flutter plugin version 75.0.1
• Dart plugin version 222.4582
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

Is that some kind of bug? How to make field names visible?

[edit]
After downgrading Flutter plugin to version 73, field names are visible again. Can anybody confirm a bug?